¿ Como se cambia el formato de fecha para poder calcular la nueva fecha despues de añadir 90 días?
Les comento que tuve que crear el google form, el google doc y google calculo, con el fin de enviar un documento.
Dentro del formulario hay una pregunta que fecha fue aprobada, y se ingreso la respuesta como dd/mm/yyyy. Pero para aplicar el javascript, como se formatearlo como mm/dd/yyyy? La razon es que tengo que calcular la nueva fecha si se agregar 90 díass a la fecha de ingreso. COmo se hace?
Muchas gracias

la logica seria asi (creo a mi punto de vista salvo sus mejores opiniones):

fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy y un # de dias para agregar
convierte el formato y divide la fecha de entrada y reorganiza en formato mm/dd/yyyy
crea y modifica la fecha y le agrega los dias
convierte la cadena y devuelve la fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy utilizando toLocaleDateString('es-MX')

yo agrego es-mx por mi eleccion, no se cual sea la tuya.
un ejemplo de lo que dije seria asi:
function agregarDias(fecha, dias) {
    let partes = fecha.split('/');
    let fechaAmericana = new 
Date(`${partes[1]}/${partes[0]}/${partes[2]}`);
    fechaAmericana.setDate(fechaAmericana.getDate() + dias);
    return fechaAmericana.toLocaleDateString('es-MX');
}

let fechaFormulario = "01/01/2024"; // formato dd/mm/yyyy
let nuevaFecha = agregarDias(fechaFormulario, 90);
console.log(nuevaFecha); // fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy


ok, bueno vamos a tratar de explicar algunos cambios..

las fechas de formato dd/mm/yyyy las vamos a reorganizar en formato yyyy-mm-dd para que new date() las pueda leer mejor
para el gettime le vamos a poner () al final osea: gettime()
y al final para la diferencias de dias: (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)

ahora si.. vamos a ver como corre despues de agregar 90 dias a la fecha de aprobacion
function agregarDias(fecha, dias) {
    let partes = fecha.split('/');
    let fechaAmericana = new 
    Date(`${partes[1]}/${partes[0]}/${partes[2]}`);
    fechaAmericana.setDate(fechaAmericana.getDate() + dias);
    return fechaAmericana.toLocaleDateString('es-MX');
}

let fechaFormulario = fechaaprobacion;
let fechavigenciadef = agregarDias(fechaFormulario, 90);
console.log(fechavigenciadef);

let fechaFormulario1 = fechaemision;

var fechaInicio = new Date(fechaFormulario1.split('/').reverse().join('-')).getTime();
var fechaFin = new Date(fechavigenciadef.split('/').reverse().join('-')).getTime();

var diferencia = Math.abs(fechaFin - fechaInicio);
var dias = Math.ceil(diferencia / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
console.log(dias);


Hola Ricxrdo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla!. No es necesario que crees otra respuesta, si hay correcciones que hacer, podes editar la anterior. Considera editar la anterior y eliminar esta. Saludos!

Muchas gracias Ricardo, esta funcionando, pero no me funciono la otra parte, esta parte es restar la diferencia entre la fecha+90 días y la fecha (la cual fue ingresada por el formulario). Te comparto mis códigos

**function agregarDias(fecha, dias) {
let partes = fecha.split('/');
let fechaAmericana = new  Date(${partes[1]}/${partes[0]}/${partes[2]});
fechaAmericana.setDate(fechaAmericana.getDate() + dias);
return fechaAmericana.toLocaleDateString('es-MX'); }
let fechaFormulario = fechaaprobacion; // formato dd/mm/yyyy   let
fechavigenciadef = agregarDias(fechaFormulario, 90);
console.log(fechavigenciadef); // fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy
let fechaFormulario1 = fechaemision;
var fechaInicio = new Date(fechaFormulario1).getTime; var fechaFin
= new Date(fechavigenciadef).getTime;
var diferencia = Math.abs(fechaFin - fechaInicio); var dias=
Math.ceil(diferencia/(10006060*24)); console.log(dias);**


Deberías editar tu pregunta y agregar este comentario en ella. Saludos.

Hola Juan, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganar otra medalla! Esta es el area de respuestas, si necesitas decirle algo a quien te responde, podes dejar un comentario utilizando la opción "Añadir un comentario" ubicada debajo de su respuesta. Por favor, elimina esta "respuesta"
